# Oracle SELECT from multiple tables problem

Tags: oracle

Can get all queries to work in an assignment but the last one of 28

28. Write a query to show the Task Id, Max Hours and Actual Hours for all task

TASK
taskid (pk)
taskname
givendate
startdate
enddate
maxhours

JOB
taskid (pk,fk)
empid (pk,fk)
hoursspent

Actual hours is hoursspent

It has me stumped, having no trouble with other JOINS but cant get this one to work without column ambigiously defined!

Comment: Please edit the question, and show example data, expected output, and what you have tried.   Thanks

Comment: hint: research `group by` and `max()` & `sum()` , if joins are no problem it is the group by clause that you now need (it comes after the where clause)

Comment: your last comment about ambiguously defined columns suggests you have the same named field in both tables, therefor you need to fully qualify these fields (eg tablename.fieldname not just fieldname).  Also have a look at aliasing your tables to save yourself some typing. In most of my roles fully qualifying all fields is a standard to ensure that these problems do not happen.

Comment: Thanks, will try some research and attempt some more options at school tomorrow